# MAX With CASE expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

Criteria:

Take EndDate of latest row per ID
If EndDate is null then  Active
If Enddate is not null then Closed

TableA

```
StartDate       EndDate            ID
  04/01/2017      06/30/2017        1   
  10/01/2017                        1
  11/01/2017      05/01/2017        2
```

Expected Results:

```
StartDate       EndDate            ID    CurrentStatus
  04/01/2017      06/30/2017        1       Active
  10/01/2017                        1       Active
  11/01/2017      11/02/2017        2       Closed
```

Sql Code:

```
SELECT * 
MAX(CASE WHEN CCP.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN 'Active' END)  
         OVER (PARTITION BY CCP.ID) AS CURRENT_STATUS
FROM TABLEA CCP
```

Can I add an Else condition for "Closed" customers?

Comment: This seems like it may be an XY problem.  Is your goal to find if any ID's have a null end date (or maybe an end date that has not passed yet, then all records for that ID are active?  otherwise they are closed?  (what happened to Id2's end date in expected results? wrap the max in a coalesce and used 'closed'?

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT * 
coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN CCP.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN 'Active' END)  
         OVER (PARTITION BY CCP.ID),'Closed') AS CURRENT_STATUS
FROM TABLEA CCP
```

Or if you have situations where end date is in the future and you need those records to be active...

This approach says if any ID has a null end date it must still be active of if any ID has a end date that is in the future, it must still be active.

The subquery identifies all ID's which are "active" based on not closed or end date is in the future; and then if such a record exists we use a case to either set all those ID's to either active or closed.

```
SELECT A1.StartDate
     , A1.EndDate
     , A1.ID
     , case when A2.ID is not null then 'Active' Else 'Closed' end As currentStatus
FROM TableA A1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct ID 
            FROM TableA 
            WHERE EndDate is null or EndDate>=Sysdate()) A2
 on A1.ID = A2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If the StartDate field is reliably issued an EndDate value before getting issued another StartDate (this is indicated by the small dataset referenced in the question), then a simple solution is to use a CASE statement can checks if a NULL enddate exists for the given ID:

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate, ID
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT EndDate 
                           FROM TABLEA T2 
                          WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.EndDate IS NULL)
             THEN 'Active'
             ELSE 'Closed'
       END AS [Current Status]
  FROM TABLEA T1
```